# Salesforce test web service call

Tags: salesforce

Here is the code for a helper function

```
public class SalesforceHelper {
    public static void waitCall(String timeout){
        System_Settings__c lnpSetting = System_Settings__c.getValues('System Properties');
        String endpoint=lnpSetting.Base_Endpoint_URL__c + 'salesforceHelper/wait?timeout=' + timeout;
        system.debug('====endpoint======'+endpoint);
        HttpRequest httpReq=new HttpRequest();  
        HttpResponse httpResp = new HttpResponse(); 
        Http http = new Http();
        httpReq.setMethod('GET'); 
        httpReq.setEndpoint(endpoint);
        String username=lnpSetting.Endpoint_Username__c;
        String password=lnpSetting.Endpoint_Password__c;    
        Blob headerValue = Blob.valueOf(username + ':' + password);
        String authorizationHeader = 'Basic ' + EncodingUtil.base64Encode(headerValue); 
        httpReq.setHeader('Authorization', authorizationHeader); 
        httpReq.setHeader('content-type','application/json; charset=utf-8');
        httpReq.setTimeout(120000);
        try{
            httpResp = http.send(httpReq);
            System.debug('Wait response' + httpResp);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            system.debug(LoggingLevel.Error, 'Error HTTP response code = ' + httpResp.getStatusCode() + '; calling '+endpoint );
        }
    }
}
```

Basically this method just using HttpRequest and HttpResponse to call the endpoint URL, and the endpoint URL is web service, and it will just return 200 after the timeout that specified in the parameter.

Now the question is, I need to write a test case to cover this method, and I don't know how to write it.. I don't know how to mock the httpcallout properly, because this method doesn't return HttpResponse, and since the code is freeze right now, I cannot modified my class to make the test case work.

So any other way I can create the test class for this method?

Answer (score 0):

You should definitely be able to use standard Http Callout Mock:

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_classes_restful_http_testing_httpcalloutmock.htm

The only difference would be that you'd only set stats code:

```
// Create a fake response
HttpResponse res = new HttpResponse();
res.setStatusCode(200);
return res;
```

and check for response code:

```
System.assertEquals(200, res.getStatusCode());
```

Comment: But I still need to call my method in test isn't it? Like ```SalesforceHelper.waitCall(20000)```, and since it doesn't return the response, how I can do the assert check?

Comment: Nope, mock simulates calling your method, it is actually never called.